# Сгенерировать ГОСТовые сертификаты libressl для openvpn

Tags: ssl, openssl, openvpn

Собрал **openvpn** с поддержкой **libressl**. Все собралось без ошибок и запускается.

Вывод команды `./libressl/bin/openssl ciphers`:

> ================================================= список сокращен GOST2012256-GOST89-GOST89 GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89:

Вывод команды `./openvpn --show-tls`:

> ================================================= GOST2012256-GOST89-GOST89 (No IANA name known to OpenVPN, use OpenSSL
>   name.) TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA256
>   TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA256
>   TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA
>   TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA GOST2001-GOST89-GOST89 (No IANA
>   name known to OpenVPN, use OpenSSL name.)

Вывод команды `./openvpn --show-ciphers`:

> ================================================= gost89 256 bit default key (fixed) (TLS client/server mode) gost89-cnt 256 bit
>   default key (fixed) (TLS client/server mode)

При попытке сгенерировать сертификат

```
./openssl req -newkey gost2001 -pkeyopt paramset:A -passout pass:aofvlgzm -subj
```

возникает вот такая ошибка:

> «/C=RU/ST=Moscow/L=Moscow/O=foo_bar/OU=foo_bar/CN=developer/
>   emailAddress=vany.egorov@gmail.com» -new >
>   certificate_signing_request.csr Generating a 1024 bit GOST2001 private
>   key Error Generating Key 140568465020576:error:32073073:GOST
>   routines:PKEY_GOST01_PARAMGEN:no parameters
>   set:gost/gostr341001_pmeth.c:193:

Помогите сгенерировать ГОСТовые сертификаты для **openvpn**.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить параметр -engine gost перед -newkey gost2001

Comment: Пробовал cnagelog говорит что engine опция удалена 
 ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/OpenBSD/LibreSSL/libressl-2.3.0-relnotes.txt
* The engine command and parameters are removed from the openssl(1).
    Previous releases removed dynamic and builtin engine support
    already.

Comment: У Вас версия openssl какая?

Comment: я собрал   libressl версии 2.3.2 так как в ней поддерживается блочное шифрование по госту.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/173

```
$ libressl genpkey -algorithm gost2001 -pkeyopt dgst:streebog256 -pkeyopt paramset:A -text

$ libressl req <...> -newkey ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:id-tc26-gost-3410-2012-512-paramSetA
```